# SweetAlert delete errors in angular5

Tags: angular, angular5, frontend, sweetalert

Working with angular5, I'm trying to use SweetAlert for delet option in my code, but I'm getting some error:

[image]

I'm using the same function as in the official  [link](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/)

This is the code in .ts

```
import * as _swal from 'sweetalert';
import { SweetAlert } from 'sweetalert/typings/core';
const swal: SweetAlert = _swal as any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clients',
  templateUrl: './clients.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clients.component.scss']
})
export class ClientsComponent implements OnInit {

  pageClients:any;

   ngOnInit() {
    this.doSearch();
    this.getAllClientsList();
  }

  delete(p:Clients){

    swal({
          title: "Are you sure?",
          text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
          icon: "warning",
          buttons: true,
          dangerMode: true,
        })
          .then((willDelete) => {
            if (willDelete) {
                  this.clientService.deleteClient(p.id)
                  .subscribe(data=>{
                  this.pageClients.content.splice(
                  this.pageClients.content.indexOf(p),1
                     );
                  },err=>{
                  console.log(err);
                   })
              swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!", {
                icon: "success",
              });
            } else {
              swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
            }
          });
    }
}
```

How to resolve this?

**EDIT**

```
delete(p:Clients){

    swal({
      title: "are you sur ?",
      text: " nce deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!!",
      type: 'warning',
      showConfirmButton: true,
      showCancelButton: true
    })
      .then((willDelete) => {

        if (willDelete) {

          this.clientService.deleteClient(p.id)
            .subscribe(data=>{
              this.pageClients.content.splice(
                this.pageClients.content.indexOf(p),1
              );
            },err=>{
              console.log(err);
            })

          swal({
           title: " great",
            type: 'success',
          });
        } else {
          swal("you have not deleted this client yet ");
        }
      });
  }
```

when this alert appears, I always get the 'great' alert, whenever I choose OK or cancel.

When I tried to print this, I understood that it's always executing the first one if(willDelete), so this client is deleted whether I choose ok or cancel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are trying to use `swal` function you need provide just the properties available on a `SweetAlertOptions` *Interface*  It has a lot of properties but this properties doesn't exist

```
icon: "warning",
 buttons: true,
 dangerMode: true,
```

Instead this you can use:

```
type :'warning',
showConfirmButton: true,
showCancelButton: true,
```

**FINAL CODE**

```
swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
  type: 'warning',
  showConfirmButton: true,
  showCancelButton: true     
})
.then((willDelete) => {
  if (willDelete) {
        this.clientService.deleteClient(p.id)
        .subscribe(data=>{
        this.pageClients.content.splice(
        this.pageClients.content.indexOf(p),1
           );
        },err=>{
        console.log(err);
         })
    swal({title:"Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!",
      type: "success",
    });
  } else {
    swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
  }
});
```

**Just to be sure**

I'm using the following src [ngx-sweetalert2](https://github.com/sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2)

```
npm install --save sweetalert2 @toverux/ngx-sweetalert2
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sweetalert-sample)